# How to fix the health bar

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating A block-breaker 2D game and I am trying to do a health bar (with 3 stars). The user's lives are supposed to decrease whenever the ball hits the collider, however, when the ball hits the invisible collider it automatically goes to the "Lose" scene. I am trying to call the variable 'health' from another script but it is not working. I know I am doing something wrong but I cannot seem to find out what it is. Any suggestions?

The below image is the inspector of LivesStars1, LivesStars2, LivesStars3
[image: The Inspector of LivesStars1, LivesStars2, LivesStars3]

Health Script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Health : MonoBehaviour {


public GameObject LivesStars1, LivesStars2, LivesStars3;
public static int health;

void Start()
{
    health = 3;
    LivesStars1.gameObject.SetActive(true); //The object LiveStars1 is being enabled
    LivesStars2.gameObject.SetActive(true); //The object LiveStars2 is being enabled
    LivesStars3.gameObject.SetActive(true); //The object LiveStars3 is being enabled

}

void Update()
{
    int health = health;

    switch (health)
    {
        case 3: //If the user doesn't lose a life all 3 lives remain
            LivesStars1.gameObject.SetActive(true); //The object LiveStars1 is being enabled
            LivesStars2.gameObject.SetActive(true); //The object LiveStars2 is being enabled
            LivesStars3.gameObject.SetActive(true); //The object LiveStars3 is being enabled
            break;
        case 2: //If the user loses one life only LivesStars3 is disabled
            LivesStars1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            LivesStars2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            LivesStars3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            break;
        case 1: //If the user loses two lives then LivesStars2 will also be disabled
            LivesStars1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            LivesStars2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            LivesStars3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            break;
        case 0: //If the uses loses all his lives then the Lose scene is enabled
            LivesStars1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            LivesStars2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            LivesStars3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            break;

    }
  }
}
```

LoadScene Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LoadScenes : MonoBehaviour {

public LevelManager lvlManager;

//If the ball hits one of the walls the colliders will be triggered
void OnTriggerEnter2D()
{
    print("The wall is triggered by the ball");
    lvlManager.LoadLevel("Lose");
    Bricks.brickCount = 0;

    if(Health.health == 0)
    {
       lvlManager.LoadLevel("Lose");
    }
}



void OnCollisionEnter2D()
{
    Debug.Log("The ball has collided with the wall");
 }

}
```

Comment: `lvlManager.LoadLevel("Lose");` this is just what you have done.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the "LoadScenes" script
When something enters a trigger OnTriggerEnter2D is called.
Before you are checking if your health is 0 you are already switching to your "Lose" Level.

This is your original code ( I added an comment to the line that causes this behaviour )

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LoadScenes : MonoBehaviour {

public LevelManager lvlManager;

//If the ball hits one of the walls the colliders will be triggered
void OnTriggerEnter2D()
{
    print("The wall is triggered by the ball");
    lvlManager.LoadLevel("Lose"); // <-- This here is your problem
    Bricks.brickCount = 0;

    if(Health.health == 0)
    {
       lvlManager.LoadLevel("Lose");
    }
}



void OnCollisionEnter2D()
{
    Debug.Log("The ball has collided with the wall");
 }

}
```

And this is what is should be:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LoadScenes : MonoBehaviour {

public LevelManager lvlManager;

//If the ball hits one of the walls the colliders will be triggered
void OnTriggerEnter2D()
{
    print("The wall is triggered by the ball");

    Bricks.brickCount = 0;

    if(Health.health == 0)
    {
       lvlManager.LoadLevel("Lose");
    }
}



void OnCollisionEnter2D()
{
    Debug.Log("The ball has collided with the wall");
 }

}
```

TLDR:
You have an extra and unnecessary `lvlManager.LoadLevel("Lose");` before you checked the player health.